# PDF to Images generate

Tags: php, imagick

I have PDF with 25 pages, I want to convert it into images with all pages.

My code:

First I have found number of pages.

```
$tmpfname= 'test_pdf.pdf';
$path = "/var/www/my_path";
$numberOfPages = $this->count_pages($tmpfname);
$numberOfPages = intval($numberOfPages); // Number of pages eg.25
```

Loop for convert pdf to images

```
for($i=0;$i<=$numberOfPages;$i++){
    $im = new imagick( $tmpfname.'['.$i.']' );
    $im->setCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
    $im->resizeImage('1024','800', Imagick::FILTER_UNDEFINED, 0.9, true);
    $im->setCompressionQuality(100);
    $im->setImageFormat('jpeg');
    $im->writeImage($path.'/'.$i.'.jpg');
    $im->clear(); 
    $im->destroy();
}
```

Function for find number of pages

```
function count_pages($pdfname) {
    $pdftext = file_get_contents($pdfname);
    $num = preg_match_all("/\/Page\W/",$pdftext, $dummy); 
    return $num;
}
```

PDF uploaded ok, and also converted images from PDF. But got this type of error after completed process:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 
'Postscript delegate failed /var/www/php/flipbook/uploads/flipbooks/61/test_pdf.pdf': 
@ error/pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/663' in /var/www/php/flipbook/application/controllers/admin/flipbooks.php:83 
Stack trace: #0 /var/www/php/flipbook/application/controllers/admin/flipbooks.php(83): 
Imagick->__construct('/var/www/php/fl...') 
#1 [internal function]: Flipbooks->create() 
#2 /var/www/php/flipbook/system/core/CodeIgniter.php(359): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) 
#3 /var/www/php/flipbook/index.php(210): require_once('/var/www/php/fl...') 
#4 {main} thrown in /var/www/php/flipbook/application/controllers/admin/flipbooks.php on line 83
```

Any buddy can help me very appreciate...

Comment: Yes, I just check it now "sudo apt-get install ghostscript" in ubuntu 12.04. ghostscript is already the newest version.

Comment: It would be useful to show the full error message

Comment: I have edited my question for more understand. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: You say `$tmpfname= 'test.pdf';` but the error says `test_pdf.pdf`

Comment: $numberOfPages = $this->count_pages($tmpfname); I have called that function for get number of pages and I have debug I got number of pages. I dont think so that the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the perfect solution from [here](http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/207409/php-pdf-converting-to-pngjpggiftif)

My new code

```
$tmpfname= 'test_pdf.pdf';
$path = "/var/www/my_path";
$numberOfPages = $this->count_pages($tmpfname);
$numberOfPages = intval($numberOfPages); // Number of pages eg.25

// Saving every page of a PDF separately as a JPG thumbnail
$images = new Imagick("test_pdf.pdf");
foreach($images as $i=>$image) {
   // Providing 0 forces thumbnail Image to maintain aspect ratio
   $image->thumbnailImage(1024,0);
   $image->writeImage($path.'/'.$i.'.jpg');
}
$images->clear();

function count_pages($pdfname) {
    $pdftext = file_get_contents($pdfname);
    $num = preg_match_all("/\/Page\W/",$pdftext, $dummy); 
    return $num;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If nothing else, you have an off by one error:

```
for($i=0;$i<=$numberOfPages;$i++){
//..
}
```

This attempts to print `numberOfPages + 1` pages as the index starts at zero.

Comment: Thank you so much for trying to help me. I have found issue, when I have putted my code "new imagick();" in for loop, I got error, I have found another solution for it.
$pdf = 'test_pdf.pdf';
$save = '/var/www/my_path/img.jpg';
exec('convert "'.$pdf.'" -colorspace RGB -resize 1024 "'.$save.'"', $output, $return_var);